# Docker: docker-compose.yml file of nginx+mariadb+php+redis

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, docker, centos7

I want to write a docker-compose.yml of nginx+mariadb+php+redis,
I read the documentation about compose-file,url:    https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#versioning
format is like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    networks:
      - back-tier
volumes:
  redis-data:
    driver: local
networks:
  front-tier:
    driver: bridge
  back-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

But I don't know how to write the compose-file of nginx+mariadb+php+redis,I want to reference some examples.And,I use the official images of Docker Hub,url: https://hub.docker.com/explore/

**ps:**software version:
OS:centos7.2
nginx:latest
php:latest
mariadb:latest
redis:latest

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something along these lines:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
      container_name: my_app
      build: .
      links:
        - redis
        - mariadb

    nginx:
      container_name: nginx
      image: nginx
      links:
        - my_app
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443

    redis:
      container_name: redis
      image: redis

    mariadb:
      container_name: mariadb
      image: mariadb
```

So create a dockerfile for your project, and extend the official PHP image by adding your files like in the readme.

This docker-compose.yml will start your container and link it to the nginx container. This means it will be available under `my_app` hostname, and you will need to add your own nginx config to pass the requests to that container.

Redis an mariadb will also be triggered by docker-compose and will be made available inside your app container under hostnames `redis` and `mariadb`.

Nginx should be the only container with ports exposed on the host.

The dockerfile above is not a complete solution, you will need to add an nginx config, and probably provide some environment variables here and there.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,  `7.0.4-cli`,  `7.0.4-fpm`, `7.0.4-zts`,which one should I choose?https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: And,in the guide for use of php7 image,it will build a new image including my project and `php-cli`, isn't it ok to build two separated images?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your project image should extend `php:7.0.4-apache` or `php:7.0.4-fpm`. The one with apache should work out of the box, while with FPM you would need to switch from sockets to TCP. One image is enough, and it will be the image that you build and deploy. For development purposes you can use other images as needed, but then you just mount your project files as a volume.